# How do I sum all values in one column based on values from range of another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

| Combi | Tons | width | bruttotime | time | time in minutes | total time for Combi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300244871 | 23.080 | 1.544,00 | 69,98 | 05:12:30 | 70,05 |  |
|  | 0,000 | 1.544,00 | 0,00 | 06:22:33 | 0,00 |  |
|  | 22.790 | 1.544,00 | 71,98 | 06:22:33 | 71,98 |  |
| 300244871 | 0,000 | 1.544,00 | 0,00 | 07:34:32 | 0,00 |  |
| 300244881 | 23.080 | 1.544,00 | 69,98 | 05:12:30 | 77,05 |  |
|  | 0,000 | 1.544,00 | 0,00 | 06:22:33 | 0,00 |  |
|  | 22.790 | 1.544,00 | 71,98 | 06:22:33 | 5,98 |  |
| 300244881 | 0,000 | 1.544,00 | 0,00 | 07:34:325,98 | 0,00 |  |

How do I sum all values in  last column (time in minutes) based on values from the Combi column (from 300244871 - to 300244871) Total time for Combi should be 142,03 for 300244871.

I have tried with below code.

```
df['time in minutes'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time in minutes'].str.replace(',', '.'))
start_value = df['Combi'].min()
end_value = df['Combi'].max()
filtered_df = df[(df['Combi'] >= start_value) & (df['Combi'] <= end_value)]
sum_result = filtered_df['time in minutes'].sum()
print(f"Sum of values for {start_value} to {end_value} in 'time in minutes': {sum_result}")
```

Comment: Looks like there is a typo in your data. `07:34:325,98` should be `07:34:32`

Comment: You do not need to filter the values to be => min and <= max. By definition all values are in this range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html). Assuming NaNs in the empty cell, create the grouper with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['time in minutes'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time in minutes'].str.replace(',', '.'))
out = (df.groupby(df['Combi'].ffill())
         .agg(**{'start': ('time', 'min'),
                 'end': ('time', 'max'),
                 'sum': ('time in minutes', 'sum')
                })
      )
```

*NB. If the empty cells are empty strings, use `df['Combi'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()` as grouper.*

Output:

```
                start       end     sum
Combi                                     
300244871.0  05:12:30  07:34:32  142.03
300244881.0  05:12:30  07:34:32   83.03
```

Using a loop:

```
for k, g in df.groupby(df['Combi'].ffill()):
    start_value = g['time'].min()
    end_value = g['time'].max()
    sum_result = g['time in minutes'].sum()
    print(f"Sum of values for {start_value} to {end_value} in 'time in minutes': {sum_result}")
```

Output:

```
Sum of values for 05:12:30 to 07:34:32 in 'time in minutes': 142.03
Sum of values for 05:12:30 to 07:34:32 in 'time in minutes': 83.03
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. How do I save output (sum) as new column associated with each first column value (row)?

Comment: `df['new'] = df.groupby(df['Combi'].ffill())['time in minutes'].transform('sum')`

Comment: since you have only the first value in Combi you could use `df['new'] = df.groupby(df['Combi'].ffill())['time in minutes'].transform('sum').where(df['Combi'].notna())`

Answer (score 0):

You possibly made a mistake by using the smallest and largest values in the 'Combi' column to filter the data. Try using a specific 'Combi' value for accurate filtering and summing of the 'time in minutes' column.